# Compress on the fly generated PDF files having embeded fonts

Tags: php, pdf, compression, size-reduction

We have an apllication generates dynamic PDF files with embeded NMSYS fonts.

But it's size is very large in comparision to the original file having larger data then dynamically generated having same fonts.

Is it possible to reduce size of such PDF with php any script, API or extention ? and why the source PDF (not generated by script) of larger contents and same fonts have less size ?

**EDIT**

Example -

[file 1](http://ewliner.com/NM%20Text%20for%20week%2027-2013.pdf)

[file 2](http://www.ewliner.com/27wknm13.pdf)

file -1 is generated by our script it's bacically showing a piece of information from file 2. There are only 5 pages in file -1 and it's of 1.2 MB and file 2 having 158 pages of similar information but of approx 4MB.

why this size difference is there?

Comment: Is the original file also a PDF file? And can you post an example of such an original / dynamically generated PDF file? It's very difficult to say what takes up space in your PDF file without actually being able to see one - there are many different reasons a PDF file can be larger than you think it should be...

Comment: @David van Driessche: I have uploaded 2 files and edited post. Please check and let me know if any other information you want from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at both files and the difference is indeed mostly font related. I saved both files optimised with Adobe Acrobat XI - this (can do) does a whole lot of optimisations but the most important difference (for file 1) comes from font subsetting:

File 1: 1.2 MB before / 253 KB after
File 2: 4.7 MB before / 3.7 MB after

Your file 2 was created using FrameMaker which normally produces pretty clean PDF (even if a very old version of Adobe Acrobat Distiller was used in this case), your file 1 was generated by DomPDF, apparently without subsetting embedded fonts.

If you look at the space audit report out of Acrobat for your first file:

[image]

You can see that the fonts take up close to 96% of the space in the file. So subsetting the font used in this file is basically your only option to make it smaller.

Different libraries or applications have different options to enable subsetting. Specifically for DOMPDF use the option DOMPDF_ENABLE_FONTSUBSETTING to enable font subsetting in the PDF files it creates:

```
def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_FONTSUBSETTING", true);
```

This then embeds only those characters actually used in the PDF file, often (depending on the amount of text and the actual font) creating much smaller files.

(DOMPDF solution added from comments to make answer more complete)

Comment: Yes am using som PDF can you please explain more about it ? how can I generate it differently ? and which library application I can use to subset the fonts

Comment: I have done this there is option in dompdf config file DOMPDF_ENABLE_FONTSUBSETTING change it's vale to true. and now file size reduced. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am confused here which answer should I accept both of you helped me to sort out this. shall I write my own answer regarding changing settings in DOMPDF config ?

Comment: I think the most important is to have the information available for others. So either write your own answer or simply edit one of the existing answers to include what you did in DOMPDF...

Comment: Here is the solution - If using DOMPDF then we can set property DOMPDF_ENABLE_FONTSUBSETTING to allow font subsetting

def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_FONTSUBSETTING", true);

It will load only those characters fonts that are actually used in the lay-out are stored in the PDF.

Answer (score 2):

The file 1 uses the TrueType DejaVuSans family of fonts and they are not subset. They take about 950kb of the PDF file. The rest are images, PDF structures, etc.
The file 2 uses TrueType Helvetica fonts and they are subset. They take much less space. Because all the text on all pages uses almost the same characters the final font size is quite small.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestion how to solve this ? what changes should I do to reduce the size to first file ? Please